# Need help removing None rows from a dask object for multiple large json files

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis, dask

Hi I am trying to flatten and parse only 7 out of many keys:value pairs from 30 nested large .json.gz files (4GB each before unzipping). I am trying doing the standard pandas and json combo but reading the rows one row at a time for 30 large json files didn't seem like the best idea so upon some searching I found dask that made this very fast. I am using this function I was able to flatten out and swiftly 7 fields I care about for each json object.

[image of jupyter notebook code and along with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vQlf.png)

The goal is to grab all json objects that have `key:screen` and `value:CAMERA`. The problem is not all json objects in these files have `key=screen`. To override that key error for rows where there is no `key=screen`, I do something I know is not recommended; try and catch block. While this works, it just creates a bunch of `None` rows and there is no way to swiftly remove them. For more clarity, the `None` rows are created in places where there was nothing to flatten because that particular json object had no `screen` key. I want to find 
either *a)* a way to filter out and flatten json files based on key and not just value. 
OR
*b)*Find a swift `dropna()` equivalent for dask bags so I can get rid of all these `None` rows in one command.

End goal is to do this for all files for march 2018 and compile them into one dataframe for further analysis.

I have tried using other commands and methods that don't involve using dask like the module `ijson` and the whole prefix, value thing(check commented out part of following code screenshot). None of the alternatives seem as swift and efficient as the `dask.bag` method given the size of my files. An ideal solution would be finding a way to get rid of the `None` rows issues.

```
import dask.bag as db
import json
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import ijson as ij
path="etl/mar2018/mongo-feedback-2018-03-05.json.gz"
# pd.read_json(path)
# b=ij.parse(path)
# print(b)

# def parse_json(json_filename):
#     with gzip.open(path,'rt', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
# #     with open(json_filename, 'rb') 
#         # load json iteratively
#         parser = ijson.parse(input_file)
# #     return ij.items(parser)
#         for prefix, event, value in parser:
#             if prefix=='screen':
#                 print(value)
# #             print(prefix)
# #             print('prefix={}, event={}, value={}'.format(prefix, event, value))


# # if __name__ == '__main__':
# parse_json(path)
# b.head()
b=db.read_text(path).map(json.loads)
# b.to_dataframe()

# b=b.filter(lambda record: record['screen'])

# # for i in b:
# #     print(i)
# # 
def flatten(record):
        try:
            return{
                'userId': record['userId'],
                'expression':record['expression'],
                'platform':record['platform'],
                'country':record['country'],
                "date":record['date']['$date'],
                "cameraImageType":record['metadataMap']["cameraImageType"],
                "screen":record['screen']
            }
        except KeyError:
            pass
df=b.map(flatten)
df.take(5)


# df.remove(None)
def filter1(record):
    if record is None:
        return record

# df.to_textfiles()
# .to_dataframe()
# p=df.map(filter1)
# df1=df-p

# # df.compute()
# # df.notnull().take(10)

# # df.dropna(how='all')
# # df.head(50)
# # p=filter(None,df)
# # list(b.filter('screen'))
# # b.count().compute()
# p=df.to_csv()
# d=df.dropna()

# d.head()

# # b.filter(lambda record: record['screen']=='CAMERA').take(10)
```

(None,
 None,
 {'userId': 'foo',
  'expression': 'bar',
  'platform': 'IOS',
  'country': 'GT',
  'date': '2018-03-04T22:58:18.000Z',
  'cameraImageType': 'typed',
  'screen': 'CAMERA'},
 None,
 None)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvHSj.png)

Comment: Hi zim68, welcome to SO. Do you mind to provide an example following this doc [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your bag contains some elements with real data as dictionaries and some with just the value `None`, where the keys could not be found - you would like to keep only the real data.

I would use the [`filter`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.filter) method:

```
b2 = b.map(flatten).filter(bool)
```

(or, to be more explicit, replace `bool` with `lambda x: x is not None`; this is a function which specifies whether you want to keep a given element or not)

Then you can write this to files, or turn into a dataframe and perform further operations on it.